# Can low priority I/O threads block the high priority threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading, clr

I am following the book CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter. With regards to I/O request priorities it says:

> Because I/O requests typically require time to process, it is possible that a
>   low-priority thread could significantly affect the responsiveness of the system by suspending
>   high-priority threads, which prevents them from getting their work done

However, Microsoft's documentation about [Scheduling Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/scheduling-threads)  states that:

> If a higher priority thread becomes runnable, the lower priority thread is preempted and the higher priority thread is allowed to execute once again

Even Jeff's own book states the following about thread scheduling:

> Higher-priority threads always preempt lower-priority threads, regardless of what the lower-priority
>   threads are executing. For example, if a priority 5 thread is running and the system determines that a
>   higher-priority thread is ready to run, the system immediately suspends the lower-priority thread (even
>   if it’s in the middle of its time-slice) and assigns the CPU to the higher-priority thread, which gets a full
>   time-slice.

Based on the above, I understand that whenever a low priority thread performing I/O operation is running and a higher priority thread is in the runnable state, the higher priority thread is executed suspending the I/O thread temporarily. How is it possible for the *low priority I/O threads to suspend the high priority threads*?

Comment: It is specific to I/O, not the rest you mention.  An example would be the disk driver, it must serialize access to the disk.  If a low priority thread gets a large read request started then the high priority thread can't get serviced for a while if wants to read as well.  It is just not much of an issue, a high priority thread should not do I/O.  Other threads can do that and notify the high priority thread that data is available.  It already largely works that way when you use async code.

Comment: Makes sense...Could you write this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?